# Get child id onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a child ID located within my "myDiv" that is randomly generated. 
 Assuming it is 'xxx' in this case, this is how the code would look like:

```
<div id="myDiv">
     <div id="xxx"><p>0</p></div>
</div>
```

I have several of these myDivs that appear on my page, however the randomly generated ID is never the same. Thus, I am trying to retrieve that ID and then change the html for only that ID from 0 to 1. Like so:

```
$('#myDiv').click(function(){
    // 1) retrieve id
    // 2) $('id').html("<p>1</p>")
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest, based on the limited information in the question:

```
// attaching the click event-handler to the 'myDiv',
// firing the anonymous function if the clicked-element has
// an id attribute:
$('#myDiv').on('click', '[id]', function(){
    // this/$(this) refers to the clicked element,
    $(this)
        // finds the <p> elements, and sets its text to:
        .find('p').text(function (i,t) {
            // i: the index of the element,
            // t: the current-text of the element

            // +t converts to a number, then we add 1 to that number:
            return +t + 1;
    });
});
```

References:

- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) to find the first div in your child which matches the selector

```
$(this).first('div[id]').html('your html')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myDiv').click(function(){
var id =    $(this).find('div').attr('id');
alert("The id is: "+id);
$('#' + id).html('<p>YOUR NEW HTML</p>')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector and [`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/).

You don't actually need to get the ID:

```js
$('#myDiv').click(function(){
    $(this).children(':first').html("<p>1</p>")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">
     <div id="xxx"><p>0</p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $('#myDiv').click(function(){
              $(this).children(':first').html("<p>1</p>")
     });
```

try this